# Magento2 - Refused to apply the style while adding one more website view

Tags: magento2, theme, multistore, less-css, multi-website

I have two website view with two store view each,

Now I want to add One more website with two store view I did all the configuration and can see the website view but css is missing getting error as Refused to apply style.

I am using weltpixel Pearl Theme

When I looked to the folder I can see only the first two website css is there and can't find the third one which I'm created

> pub/static/version1562780854/frontend/Pearl/weltpixel/en_US/WeltPixel_CustomHeader/css

I am stuck with this, please someone give me solution to this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Amy, did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to deploy the static content & clear cache with

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
bin/magento cache:clean
```

Comment: I have run the commands, it is not working.